# Getting a Controls.Image Width and Height

Tags: .net, wpf, image-processing, bitmap

I'm new to WPF and am trying to use a a Controls.Image. I have it set to stretch when the form expands. I am trying to generate a Drawing.Bitmap at runtime to display on the Controls.Image in WPF. When I generate the Drawing.Bitmap I only want to create one as big as the Image control on the screen is (don't waste cpu cycles). To create the image I have the following code. `Bitmap bImage = new Bitmap((int)imgInput.Width, (int)imgInput.Height);`imgInput is the Controls.Image and bImage obviously is the Drawing.Bitmap. However the imgInput.Width and Height are showing as 0 at runtime although they are definitely not at design time. If I don't try to dynamically stretch the image to expand with the window there is no issue it shows as expected. So how do I actually get the image. Also does anyone have a better way than creating a Drawing.Bitmap in memory and converting it over to a ImageSource for WPF? I am not loading an image from a URI or anything like that I have to create it in memory.

I am binding the image by the following code

```
            imgInput.Source = loadBitmap(bImage);

    }
    [DllImport("gdi32")]
    static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

    public static BitmapSource loadBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
    {
        BitmapSource bs = null;
        IntPtr ip = source.GetHbitmap();
        try
        {
            bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip,
               IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
               System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally
        {
            DeleteObject(ip);
        }

        return bs;
    }
```

Comment: how are you binding the bitmap to the Image? Do you have width/height explicitly set for you image  in XAML?

Comment: The image width and height are set to auto but this is a must to allow for a horizontal and vertical alignment to be set to stretch i believe

Comment: that would explain it - the Image will re-size to its content, so it doesn't have any width until you bind a bitmap to it

Comment: The image should only re size to its parent, when its parent re sizes so should it

Comment: I guess the last question is, Is there something better to use rather than Bitmap that would allow me to specify the value of each pixel and be more efficient than converting a Bitmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image creation from bitmap looks ok to me.

The XAML image will re-size depending on the width/height of the bitmap itself and how much space is "available". WPF uses a two pass layout system - in the first round each control is asked how much space it desires, in the second each control is assigned a width/height.

Before binding the bitmap and if none of the ancestors of your image control have a fixed/maximum width you cannot retrieve the image height, simply because there is none set yet.

One approach would be setting the width/height of the Image based on an ancestor via binding, again this would require some set width/height on the container.

**Example for Grid container:**

```
<Image Source="sample.png" 
        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},Path=ActualWidth}" 
        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},Path=ActualHeight}" />
```

Also you want to choose your container carefully - a `StackPanel` i.e. will always grow with its children (vertically if Orientation is Horizontal and vice versa)  unless you specify a fixed or maximum width/height. Other containers behave differently, i.e. a `UniformGrid` would size all its children equally. I would try a Grid with only one row first.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Height` and `Width` of the `Source` you need to change you code to

```
Bitmap bImage = new Bitmap((int)imgInput.Source.Width, (int)imgInput.Source.Height);
```

`imgInput.Width` and `imgInput.Height` gives the Height and Width of the Control,

`imgInput.Source.Width` and `imgInput.Source.Height` gives the Height and Width of the Source

Comment: Ok what happens if the initial source is null?

Comment: its not possible to get the size of a null object. you need to validate that.

Comment: In the scenario of the question the source has not been set yet so it will always be null, this approach won't work